# Basic epidemiological models in R

Tags: r, epidemiology

To support an education project around neglected infectious diseases in Sub-Saharan Africa, I aim to estimate and report some very basic epidemiological models in R to build intuition and understanding with the students.

I have been searching for a little bit (to no avail) - does anyone know of basic R-based modules / models (compartmental or agent-based) that I could use? For example - SIR models similar to these Python models (http://wiki.deductivethinking.com/wiki/Program_3.1)

Comment: I would start with something like this: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Epi/Epi.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Good epidemiology packages for R to look at (I only included R packages **curated** in CRAN task views):

- [Epi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Epi/index.html) in the [Survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html) task view
- [epibasix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epibasix/index.html) in the [ClinicalTrials](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ClinicalTrials.html) task view
- [epicalc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epicalc/index.html) in the [ClinicalTrials](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ClinicalTrials.html) task view
- [epiR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epiR/index.html) in both the [Survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html) task view and the [MetaAnalysis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MetaAnalysis.html) task view

Comment: these are mostly for non-infectious diseases, I think, not for dynamical (SIR-type) models

Comment: It's not a package, but http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/eeid/ may have some useful material.

Comment: or https://github.com/smjenness/Shiny/blob/master/SIR/ui.R

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EpiModel/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[epitools: Epidemiology Tools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epitools/index.html) is another good one.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [pomp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pomp/) package. The last pages of its [vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pomp/vignettes/intro_to_pomp.pdf) show how to create SIR models of varying complexity.